# python itertools with islice error

Tags: python

I'm still learning python and I have the code below but it is not working:

```
from itertools import *

startword = ["start",]
stopword = ["stop",]
text = "this is a text that starts with some test stuff and then after that it stop right here!"

for i in islice(text.split(" "), startword, stopword):
    print i
```

I'm trying to print the words between the start and stop without knowing how many words are there in between.
from the error I'm getting it look like I need an integer for start and stop parameters for islice. here is the error "`ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= maxing.`"
any other itertool that I can use?!

Thanks,

Comment: Slicing uses indices, not values.  you can get the indice of that value with the `.index()` method but you will A: need to  store the return value of `text.split(" ")` before passing it into islice to use .index correctly and B: use the correct word that represents your start, `"start"` is not present in your sentence but `"starts"` is.

Comment: baaaaam that did it. Thanks a lot @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I need to eat the same food you eat to be as smart as you are :))

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the index of 'start' and 'stop' and then you provide
    two integer values, not strings:

```
for i in islice(text.split(" "), startword_index, stopword_index):
    print i
```

Comment: Thank you and excuse my ignorance. When you say index, do you mean it in the sense of text[5] for the start word index and text[15] ?

Comment: Yes, there's a number of different ways to figure out them.  You're welcome.

Comment: Mind you, if you know the index, you may as well just slice; `islice` is inefficient for skipping many values if the data is already in memory anyway, it has to iterate through to the start point, and while it does it efficiently, if it's already a `list`, real slicing can skip that entirely.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, `islice` is a poor choice; you have all the data in memory, in a realized sequence, so `islice` is just wasting time iterating the leading values. There are many better ways to handle this, either using `index` to find the `start` and `end` indices and doing a true slice, or to get more clever, and reduce the work by splitting out the `start/end` delimited section and only splitting that part to extract words. For example:

```
text = "this is a text that starts with some test stuff and then after that it stop right here!"

_, text = text.split('start', 1)  # Remove start and stuff before it
text, _ = text.rsplit('stop', 1)  # Remove stop and stuff after it

for word in text.split():  # Split what remains on whitespace
    print word
```

Mind you, this still isn't quite right (your bounded region begins with "starts" not "start", so you end up with a leading "word" of "s"), but switching to `re.split` with appropriate bounding and wildcarding could be used to fix that in whatever way is appropriate to your scenario.

Comment: A true python slice like operation would leave in the start value, Also maybe use a different variable name so the original text is still available.  Other then that I like this solution.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger this is perfect explanation. how would it look if my starting word is more than "starts" say "starts with"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Yar, alternate variables to preserve the original string aren't a bad idea. I avoided preserving `start` simply because I felt it was closer to a delimiter than part of the data to be kept, but that's obviously problem dependent.

Comment: @FrankBud: You can change the first `split` argument to whatever you like, it will be removed, as will everything before it. If it's more complex (any word that begins with `start`, but might have trailing additional characters), it's probably best to move to `re.split` with a pattern like `r'\bstart\w*\b'`.